# hover.com and Heroku.com integration

Tags: heroku, dns

I've been trying to understand how to setup my heroku app, to work with a domain I've bought.

Reading this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns#configure-dns-servers - I don't understand what should I do in the "Configure DNS Servers".

What exactly should be done in order to configure the DNS in hover.com?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Those are specific instructions for [zerigo](http://www.zerigo.com). If you want to use hover all you have to do is follow this [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

I should note that hover doesn't really support naked domains in this way but there are other services that you could rely on for that. I bothered them once about it and they said they were working on it so you may be able to have a naked domain on hover in the future.